# Desktop icons showing files of home

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment, desktop

I think at some point I might have accidentally moved the `Desktop` folder onto my `Pictures` folder, and when I noticed I reverted it. But ever since then, the icons shown in my graphical desktop are of the files and folders in `home`.

I am on Ubuntu 17.10 with gnome. Tried turning off the option `Show Desktop Icons` in `Tweak Tools` and then turning it back on, but it didn't do anything.

My theory is that there was a `symlink` of some sort that changed, or was deleted, when the `Desktop` folder wasn't where it was supposed to be. But I don't know where to look to be able to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `ls -dl ~ ~/Desktop`?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 42 mariel mariel 4096 dic 18 17:23 /home/mariel
drwxr-xr-x  4 mariel mariel 4096 dic 18 11:19 /home/mariel/Desktop
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally found an answer [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/desktop-showing-the-contents-of-home-folder-on-desktop-in-fedora-8-a-649528/).I have restarted my computer and now everything is behaving as it should.

The problem seemed to be in  the file`~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`: there was a line appearing like `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"` when it should have made reference to `$HOME/Desktop`.

Why or how it changed I dont know.

Comment: Five years later and I'm really grateful to see this answer as I was having a hard time even coming up with the words to describe the problem!

Comment: I change this file, and create the folder Desktop, but the directory Desktop is becoming a symlink always on restart